# Run command from sudo su

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, su

On a machine I (`tlous`) have been given access to open a shell as another user (`serviceAccount`)

Executing: `sudo su - serviceAccount` has the desired effect of opening a shell as this `serviceAccount` user. So far so good.

This is nice, but I want to run a command as this user without opening a shell.

Let's say the command is `whoami`

I've tried:

`sudo -u serviceAccount whoami`

> Sorry, user tlous is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/whoami' as serviceAccount ...

`sudo su - serviceAccount -c whoami`

> Sorry, user tlous is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - serviceAccount -c whoami' ...

And other variations.
What am I missing? Can this be done in a oneliner?
The reason is that I actually want to run this as an ssh command:
`ssh -t tlous@server.example.com sudo su - serviceAccount -c whoami`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the `sudoers` file on the remote side specifies the exact command you can run and it's `su - serviceAccount`. One or more additional options (like `-c`) will make the command not qualify. Any solution should use the exact `su - serviceAccount` command.

There is a way to do something about it, but it's not perfect. Start by running this on the server:

```
echo whoami | sudo su - serviceAccount
```

(`sudo` without `-S` will use the terminal to ask for your password (if needed) despite the redirection).

To make the approach more general, create a script on the server:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '%s ' "$@" | sudo su - serviceAccount
```

Save it as `su-ser`, and make it executable. Now you can test these:

```
./su-ser whoami
./su-ser 'whoami; whoami'
./su-ser ls -l
./su-ser 'ls -l'
```

Note these quotes don't propagate to the shell spawned by `su`. Each time `printf` builds a command from arguments that the script gets, this is passed as a *string* and then *parsed* by the final shell, with word splitting, globbing and such. This means all these

```
./su-ser echo 1 2 3
./su-ser echo "1 2             3"
./su-ser "echo 1 2             3"
```

will print `1 2 3`. To pass a *quoted* string you need to quote quotes, e.g.:

```
./su-ser 'echo "1 2             3"'
```

The next step is to trigger this remote script from your local computer:

```
ssh -t tlous@server.example.com '"/path/to/su-ser" whoami'
```

You need `-t` in case `sudo` asks for the password. From the `ssh` command in your question body I can tell you probably understand this.

Note `ssh` also builds a command *string*. The above quoting would work even if `/path/to/su-ser` contained spaces. On the other hand, if the path is without spaces (and without characters like `;`, `*`), a totally unquoted `ssh … /path/to/su-ser whoami` will work as well.

Proper quoting is not a trivial task at this point. Let's analyze what happens to the command.

0. At first your local shell parses the string. It uses the most outer quotes (if any) to parse it right.
1. `ssh` gets its arguments as an array. The quotes used up by the shell don't get this far.
2. `ssh` decides which arguments should be passed to the remote side and builds a string (in similar manner to `printf` in our remote script).
3. This string is then parsed by the remote shell (the one spawned by `sshd` on the server). The remote shell uses the (now) most outer quotes (if any) to parse it right.
4. `su-ser` gets its arguments as an array. The quotes used up by the remote shell don't get this far.
5. `su-ser` builds a string.
6. This string is then parsed by yet another shell (spawned by `su` on the server). The shell uses the (now) most outer quotes (if any) to parse it right.
7. The command(s) you passed gets its arguments as an array. The quotes used up by the last shell don't get this far.

This means sometimes you need *three* levels of quotes to get the right result. An uncomplicated local command like

```
echo "1 2             3"
```

becomes

```
ssh -t tlous@server.example.com "'/path/to/su-ser' 'echo \"1 2             3\"'"
```

where the unescaped double-quotes get stripped by the local shell, the single-quotes get stripped by the remote shell; finally the escaped double-quotes (that in fact become unescaped as soon as the local shell strips the unescaped ones) tell the shell spawned by `su` that the string with multiple spaces is a single argument to `echo`. This way the output is

```
1 2             3
```

---

Another problem is the remote script passes commands to stdin of the final shell, so you can't easily use its stdin for another purpose. E.g. `cat; whoami` (try it) should print back whatever lines you type (terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), then the output of `whoami`. However if you run this on the server:

```
./su-ser 'cat; whoami'
```

`cat` will terminate immediately. This should work:

```
./su-ser 'cat /dev/tty; whoami'
```

(Again, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to terminate `cat`). Now compare the behavior of this:

```
./su-ser '
whoami
whoami
whoami
'
```

to this:

```
./su-ser '
whoami
cat
whoami
'
```

The same stream feeds `cat` and the shell; it's not a good thing. Establishing separate channels for actual commands and the real stdin may not be easy because `sudo` by default closes additional file descriptors and sets a new, minimal environment. I *guess* a contraption using temporary files/fifos would work, but this is so hairy I won't even try.

So the script may or may not be enough for you; it depends on commands you need to run. Now you know a couple of its limitations. Good luck.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the thorough explanation!